# disabling mapply automatically converting Dates to numeric

Tags: r

I've noticed that when you do this:

```
mapply(function(x) { x }, c(as.Date('2014-1-1'), as.Date('2014-2-2')))
```

R automatically converts your vector of Dates into a vector of numbers. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

I know that you can wrap the result in as.Date(..., origin='1970-1-1'), but I can only imagine there has to be a better solution here.

Comment: side note : You should maybe rewrite your code example , this is not the right way to use `mapply`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: I mean that the usual way to use `mapply` is `mapply(function(x,y),X,Y)` for example `mapply(rep, 1:4, 4:1)`. You are using it as `sapply/lapply`. As I already mentioned this only a side note.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with the way `mapply` simplifies its result through `simplify2array`.

```
x <- list(as.Date('2014-1-1'), as.Date('2014-2-2'))
simplify2array(x, higher = FALSE)
# [1] 16071 16103
```

You can turn off the simplification and then reduce the list manually.

```
do.call(c, mapply(I, x, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
# [1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-02"
```

Or you can use `Map` along with `Reduce` (or `do.call`)

```
Reduce(c, Map(I, x))
# [1] "2014-01-01" "2014-02-02"
```

`Map` is basically `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` and I use `I` in place of `function(x) { x }` because it just returns its input as-is.

Comment: Using `I` instead of `(` makes more sense to me.

Comment: Oh yeah, that works too.  Didn't think about that.  Made the edit

Comment: I like the Reduce(c, Map(I, x)) approach the best of everything discussed.  Thanks!

Comment: @chucktaylor FYI , `Reduce` is generally slower than `do.call`.