# How to avoid R converting dates to numeric automatically?

Tags: r

How to avoid R converting dates to numeric in a for loop? This is related to this question that shows the same behavior for mapply [disabling mapply automatically converting Dates to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536119/disabling-mapply-automatically-converting-dates-to-numeric)

```
date <- c('2008-02-20','2009-10-05')
date <- as.Date(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
date
[1] "2008-02-20" "2009-10-05"
for (i in date) print(i)
[1] 13929
[1] 14522
```

[disabling mapply automatically converting Dates to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536119/disabling-mapply-automatically-converting-dates-to-numeric)

## Edit

I have reopened this question since the duplicate [Looping over a datetime object results in a numeric iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-datetime-object-results-in-a-numeric-iterator) asks **why** R loops convert date and datetime objects to numeric, this question asks **how to avoid** that behavior. And the answer is to the point solving the problem, unlike the accepted and other answers in the duplicate, that correctly answer that other question.

Comment: The `Date` class in Base R stores dates as number of days since the epoch, so what you are seeing is the real underlying data.  Your question is really about presentation of that data.

Comment: It's a hassle, but you can reconvert: `for (i in date) print(as.Date(i, origin = '1970-01-01'))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `for` loop coerces the sequence to vector, unless it is vector, list, or some other things.  `date` is not a vector, and there is no such thing as vector of dates.  So you need `as.list` to protect it from coercion to vector:

```
for (d in as.list(date)) print(d)
```